# Recharts how to display an additional diagonal line with different data set to a line chart

Tags: reactjs, line, recharts

What I am trying to do is the following:

[image]

But I can't manage to get it working. I was able to get the data to read in from 2 different data sources but it somehow does not render the second line properly on the x-axis.

Here is the example code:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import { LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, ReferenceLine } from "recharts";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const data = [];

const maxBudget = 300;
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  let d = {
    day: i,
    value: Math.random() * (maxBudget + 50) + 100
  };

  data.push(d);
}

const testline = [{ x: 0, y: 300 }, { x: 20, y: 0 }]

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <LineChart
      width={500}
      height={300}
      
      margin={{ top: 5, right: 20, bottom: 5, left: 0 }}
    >
      <Line type="monotone" data={data} dataKey="value" stroke="#8884d8" dot={false} />
      <Line type="linear" data={testline} dataKey="y" stroke="#FF3333" dot={false} strokeWidth={2} />
      <XAxis dataKey="day" type="number" tickCount={11} />
      <YAxis />
      <ReferenceLine
        y={maxBudget}
        label={{
          position: "center",
          value: "Max budget"
        }}
        strokeDasharray="5 5"
      />
    </LineChart>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I m stupid. I just found it out by myself. Sometimes you don't see the wood for the trees for days :(.

The x value must be the same as defined in the XAxis so I had to change x:0 to day:0:

```
const testline = [{ day: 0, y: 300 }, { day: 20, y: 0 }]
```

Now it works